# pnotify refuses to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded the pnotify jquery plugin  from [Pines Notify](http://pinesframework.org/pnotify)

Simply it tells me to add the required js and css files and on document ready the following should work !

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.pnotify({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Errors found in form',
        text: 'Please check all form data, some items were invalid.',
        opacity: 0.95,
        hide:false,
        history: false,
        sticker: false
    });    
});
```

But it just keeps giving me the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)}
>   has no method 'pnotify'

And the silliest thing is that im visual VS 2012 and from within the dev environment it shows me pnotify as a function of '$' as intellisense !

What could i be doing wrong ?

Comment: The pnotify script is not loading correctly. Look in the network tab of the browser dev tools to confirm.

Comment: checked that too, its loading perfectly well :(

Comment: Ok found the problem :P I had included 2 different versions of jquery in the page.

Answer (score 0):

with PNotify2.01, you can use it with reguirejs

main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
   paths: {
      pnotify: "/Static/plugins/pnotify/pnotify.custom.min"
   }
});
```

Notify.js

```
define(['pnotify'], function () {
  return {
     SimpleNotice: function () {
        return new PNotify('Check me out! I\'m a notice.');
     }
  };
});
```

I copy this from my production code (Durandal framework)